# No COMPONENT named markup://svg found

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, error-messages, svg-icon, svg

After downloading the SLDS I have copied a detail form from the lightning design system to the salesforce console. But when I save there is a popup saying 
**"No COMPONENT named markup://svg found"**.

I have found in **some other topics** that I have to replace `< svg>`

```
< svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
   < use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#down">< /use>
< /svg
```

by  `lightning:icon iconName=...."`

**BUT** I don't understand how it can replace it exactly.. Both are very different and I can't figure out how it can replace it. That's why I am making a new topic.
How exactly do we replace it?

Thank you !

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:icon/example

Answer (score 2):

We can't use svg directly, you have to use [lightning:icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:icon/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleIconVariants) .

Now to convert your SVG into lightning:icon

SVG :

```
< svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
   < use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#down">< /use>
< /svg
```

This if you read carefully, it means from `utility` type of icon use `down` icon.

Thus your iconName will be `utility:down`

```
 <lightning:icon iconName="utility:down"></lightning:icon>
```

Comment: So I replace it by what you've written? I have just done it, but the page is not like it has to be, i don't get it.. It doesn't work

Comment: That should be it.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: what doesnt work?

Comment: I should have 1 down icon and some edit icons, but nothing, there are only some huge buttons